# Using a trained sentiment analysis model, TF-IDF and logistic regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sentiment-analysis, tf-idf

I'm doing a sentiment analysis project on a Twitter dataset. I used TF-IDF feature extraction and a logistic regression model for classification. So far I've trained the model with the following:

```
def get_tfidf_features(train_fit, ngrams=(1,1)):
    vector = TfidfVectorizer(ngrams, sublinear_tf=True)
    vector.fit(train_fit)
    return vector

X = tf_vector.transform(df['text'])

y = df['sentiment']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.01, random_state = 42)

LR_model = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs')
LR_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_predict_lr = LR_model.predict(X_test)
```

This logistic regression model was trained on a dataset of about 1.5 million tweets. I have a set of about 18,000 tweets and I want to use this model to predict the sentiment scores for the tweets in this new dataset. I'm at a loss of how to actually apply this trained model to new data. The head of this new dataframe `df_chi` looks like this:

[image]

which has shape (18393, 7). I want to take the trained model I already have, apply it to the text column, and create a new `sentiment` column with those predicted scores in the `df_chi` dataframe. (Note: the image doesn't show cleaned text, but I'll do that.)

I'm a ML noob and I've never taken a trained model and applied it to new data. My confusion starts with extracting features from the `df_chi` text with TF-IDF. I attempted to do this (total guess):

```
tf_vector = get_tfidf_features(df_chi['text'])
X = tf_vector.transform(df_chi['text'])
df_chi['sentiment'] = LR_model.predict(X)
```

which gives the following ValueError:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-188-0cf1a4f34c8b> in <module>
      1 tf_vector = get_tfidf_features(df_chi['text'])
      2 X = tf_vector.transform(df_chi['text'])
----> 3 df_chi['sentiment'] = LR_model.predict(X)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_base.py in predict(self, X)
    291             Predicted class label per sample.
    292         """
--> 293         scores = self.decision_function(X)
    294         if len(scores.shape) == 1:
    295             indices = (scores > 0).astype(np.int)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_base.py in decision_function(self, X)
    271         if X.shape[1] != n_features:
    272             raise ValueError("X has %d features per sample; expecting %d"
--> 273                              % (X.shape[1], n_features))
    274 
    275         scores = safe_sparse_dot(X, self.coef_.T,

ValueError: X has 22806 features per sample; expecting 265054
```

Pretty sure my whole approach to applying the trained model on the new data is incorrect. What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Noodled around with this and came up with the following solution:

```
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()
X_chi = tfidf.fit_transform(df_chi['text'])

X1 = pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(X)
X_chi1 = pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(X_chi)

not_existing_cols = [c for c in X1.columns.tolist() if c not in X_chi1]
X_chi1 = X_chi1.reindex(X_chi1.columns.tolist() + not_existing_cols, axis=1)
#X_chi.fillna(0, inplace=True)
X_chi1 = X_chi1[X1.columns.tolist()]
a = LR_model.predict(X_chi1)
df_chi['sentiment'] = a
```

Solution inspired by [Logistic regression: X has 667 features per sample; expecting 74869](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62371380/logistic-regression-x-has-667-features-per-sample-expecting-74869)

Looks a little clumsy, though. If it works it works, I guess. Though I suspect there might be a better way to do this, no?